# How to edit request host headers in c# through web request?

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

When i'm trying to edit the Host key on Request.Headers under console application i'm getting exception that says:

```
The 'Host' header cannot be modified directly.
Parameter name: name
```

So how can i change it?

Comment: Hi Udi. Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've seen the .Net Fx does not allow to edit the host header, but since .Net Fx 4.0 there is a seperate 'Host' definition on the HttpWebRequest object. You can use it like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/");
request.Host = "yourdomain.com";
```

Hope that helps you out.